# How to reference the users model using Django-Allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm looking to use get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=1) for a allauth user but I don't know how to create the MyModel part.

Comment: `how to create the MyModel part.` I guess you create MyModel

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to get the user object from a primary key, simply import the user model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

And then you may now reference it:

```
user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Django Annoying" project has an **AutoOneToOneField** (described at https://github.com/skorokithakis/django-annoying#autoonetoonefield) which can be very handy in creating "profile tables" that are to have a 1:1 relationship to Django's User-table.  Whereas Django's foreign-key field would throw an exception if a record doesn't exist, this field-type will automagically create one on-the-fly.  Very, very handy:  now you can simply refer to the profile-table entry, trusting that a record will actually be there, because it will be.